# What is the structural difference between "Do they sing ?" and "Would they sing" ? (interrogative sentence)

Tags: grammar, meaning, questions, comparative-constructions

Somehow i don't know how to describe the structural difference between them. Can someone help me?    (Thanks for help)

Comment: They're both "interrogatives". One asks about what they ***actually*** do (by implication, in *current circumstances*), the other asks what they ***would*** do (in some *unspecified circumstances*). But what do you mean by "structural difference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is essentially the same:

> [Auxiliary verb] [Subject] [Verb (bare infinitive)]

The only difference is that "would" is a modal verb.  Do is an auxiliary verb which is introduced solely for the purpose of forming the question.

So no difference in structure, only a difference in meaning.